# Specify formatting information in Excel forumla

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, worksheet-function

Is there a way to specify the formatting in an excel formula?

```
=IF(A1="Large","This is BIG","This is small")
```

Where "BIG" is of a font size larger than the text for "small"?

*(I'm aware of conditional formatting. That's not what I'm after.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a UDF in VBA that will return the font size

```
Function FontSize(rCell As Range) As Long
    Application.Volatile
    FontSize = rCell.Font.Size
End Function
```

But it won't update just because you change the font size - that is changing the font size doesn't cause Excel to recalculate.  You could, again using VBA, try to capture all the buttons that change the font size and force a recalc when the user presses them, but...

I think my answer is: there's really no good way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to check font size only?
This could be impossible I would say.

You could set multiple sizes for font in single cell, so it would be hard to make function that will work well on that.

For checking other infos about single cell there is a CELL function

> =CELL("info_type",[reference])

Comment: I'm not checking, just trying to set different font values within the equation. I guess calculations only output standard text

Comment: I've never heard of anything like formatting result of formula. The only options could be VBA then if you don't want to use Conditional Formatting.